# Autodetecting variables for URL variables

Tags: civicrm.settings.php

I am having an issue in Settings - Resource URLs where the [civicrm.files] variable is detecting incorrectly. It's actually detecting as https://www.mydomain.org/usr/home/webhoster/mydomain.org/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/

Is there an override I can put in my civi URL variable settings file to make it right? Or do I need to get a tweak to my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those tokens aren't working for you, it's OK to use the absolute URL or path without the token instead. Would that solve the problem for you?

```
https://www.example.org/wp-content/plugins/files/civicrm/
```

There seem to have been a few questions about this recently. I haven't run into it myself, but got an impression this may relate to symlinks in the webserver path.

There has been a bit of work recently regarding miscalculation of `[civicrm.files]` values - contributing information to these linked discussions may help to get the problem resolved:

- [CRM-20609: File URL when CiviCRM detects Drupal doesn't match path set by [civicrm.files]](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20609)
- [CRM-19303: CKEditor configuration can't be edited on a Drupal multisite installation](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19303)
- Lots of discussion of this in [PR9458](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9458)

Comment: Yeah it works fine, and it could well be a symlink issue. Thanks anyway!